# Asserting Meta Tags using Selenium/webdriver (java)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have the following piece of html:

```
<head>
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"></meta>
</head>
```

Using Selenium Webdriver (Cucumber) I've the following piece of code which doesn't seem to be working:

```
    @and("^Meta is being checked with property \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void check_meta(String property) throws Throwable {
    String meta = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//meta[contains(text(), \"" + property + "\")]")).getText();
    Assert.assertTrue(meta.contains(property));
}
```

I'm trying to assert if twitter:card is present, but it gives me assertion errors now.
What am I doing wrong? What is the correct definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your xpath is checking the `text()` of the meta tag.  The `text()` will return what's in the block.

```
<meta ....></meta>
          /\  It will return what's in here.
```

What YOU want, is to validate the meta `content` attribute.

Try:

```
Assert.assertTrue(
    driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("meta[name='twitter\\:card']")).size() > 0
);
```

this will validate that the `<meta name="twitter:card" ... />` is there, but not checking the content.

Comment: It's not quite working... the only thing I want to do is assert if twitter:card is actually present or not. As long as twitter:card is in one of the META tags, I'm good.

Comment: edited.  It was difficult trying to determine your intentions :)

Comment: edited my intentions as well :) I'm using         Assert.assertTrue(
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("meta")).getAttribute("name").equals(property)
        ); now, but it still gives me assertion errors. I don't care which meta tag I'm validating